# How to know the max capacity of a JMS queue?

Tags: jms

How would I know the maximum number of messages a JMS Queue can hold?

Regards
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, based on the raw JMS API.  Such functionality might be available in a particular vendor's implementation via auxiliary classes or JMX.  For instance, Apache ActiveMQ has numerous classes to assist in interacting with the broker, beyond the basic API.